# Getting Latest/Top orderID for each customer in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database where it records all the orders of customers. What I'm trying to do is not to get all the orders of each customer, but the latest order the customer made with us. I have already do this by using Sub-Select statement, but because of how many data there is, it is taking alot of time to retrieve. So I was wondering is there another way around this that can speed it up?

Here's the code of using Sub-Select statement I've written:

```
SELECT  Customer.CustomerId,
        Customer.Firstname + ' ' + Customer.Surname AS [Customer Name],
        (SELECT TOP(1) Orders.OrderId
        FROM Orders
        WHERE Orders.CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId
        ORDER BY Orders.OrderId DESC),
        (SELECT TOP(1) Orders.Item
        FROM Orders
        WHERE Orders.CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId
        ORDER BY Orders.OrderId DESC)
FROM Customer
```

Any help or info on how to improve this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: ...and why would a customer even have an order id column?

Comment: sorry made a correction - It's the order table that have the customer ID

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT T1.CustomerID,T1.OrderID,T2.OrderItem
FROM
   (SELECT C.CustomerID,MAX(O.OrderID) as OrderID
    FROM Customer C JOIN 
      Orders O ON C.CustomerID=O.CustomerID
    GROUP BY C.CustomerID) T1 
    JOIN
   (SELECT OrderID,Item
    FROM Orders) T2 ON T1.OrderID=T2.OrderID
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9af1c7/3).

Comment: hmm... Mind if I ask why max() and not Top()?? Thanks

Comment: @Danny: MAX is a little bit faster because it uses `Stream Aggregation`. For `Order by`, the table data should be sorted before finding the top record which takes more time.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If that's the case, shouldn't we always be using MAX instead of TOP then??

Comment: @Danny: Consider the scenario: If we want to select all the details of an employee who has the highest salary, we cannot use MAX (unless we use join). Because, we will have to use `GROUP BY` which ofcourse retrieves more than one row. So in that case, we can use `TOP`.

Answer (score 0):

1. If there are indexes created ,rebuilt/refresh the indexes which will help in increasing the performance of the query.
2. Try creating **non clustered** indexes which will speed up the execution of the query.

Answer (score 0):

might be this is helpful for you

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT c.CustomerName, 
           c.OrderID, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.CustomerName 
                                 ORDER BY c.CustomerName  DESC) AS rk
      FROM Customers c
      join Orders j c.OrderID = j.OrderId
      )
SELECT a.*
  FROM cte a
 WHERE a.rk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using row_number gives better results, so you could try something like this:

```
select * from (
  SELECT
    C.CustomerId,
    C.Firstname + ' ' + C.Surname AS [Customer Name],
    O.OrderId,
    O.Item,
    row_number() over (partition by O.CustomerId order by O.OrderId desc) as RN
  FROM
    Customer C
    join Orders O on O.CustomerId = O.CustomerId
) X
where RN = 1
```

If there's a lot of orders and customers this can be slow too since there's no search criteria. You should also check indexing, especially Orders.CustomerId.

Didn't try this, so hopefully there's no syntax errors :)